# Convergence of $\{na_n\}$ when $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I solved if $a_0>0, a_{n+1}=\ln(1+a_n)$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} {na_n}=2$ 
And, if $0<a_0<1, a_{n+1}=a_n -a^2_{n}$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} {na_n}=1$ 
So, I think if real function $f$ has continuous second derivative in $[0,a]$ for positive real number $a$ 
and $f(0)=0,f'(0)=1,f''(x)<0$ when $x \in [0,a] $ and $0<a_0<a,a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} {na_n}= \frac 2 {- f''(0)}$ 
I want to prove it. So I use Taylor Theorem to prove this. 
First, I want to prove that there is a positive real number $m, M$ such that $m \leq na_n \leq M$ for all $n$

 But I cannot prove this. How to prove it? There is another different idea to prove this?

Comment: I think that you have $f^{\prime}(0)=1$. Now write for $x $ close to $0$ $f(x)=x+x^2 f^{\prime\prime}(c)/2$, with $0<c<x$, consider $u_n=\frac                          {1}{a_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{a_n}$, and show that $u_n\to -f^{\prime\prime}(0)/2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f\in C^3$, $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)=1$, $f''(0)<0$, and $a_0>0$, $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$, then
$$
na_n\to -\frac{2}{f''(0)} \tag{1}
$$
To show that, first observe that $a_n\to 0$, and then
$$
\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{a_n}=\frac{a_n-f(a_n)}{a_na_{n+1}}=\frac{a_n-\big(a_n+\frac{1}{2}f''(0)a_n^2+{\mathcal O}(a_n^3)\big)}{a_n\big(a_n+f''(0)a_n^2+{\mathcal O}(a_n^3)\big)} \\=
\frac{-\frac{1}{2}f''(0)+{\mathcal O}(a_n)}{1+\frac{1}{2}f''(0)a_n+{\mathcal O}(a_n^2)}\to -\frac{1}{2}f''(0). 
$$
[Stolz-Cezàro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) implies that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{a_n}}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{a_n}}{(n+1)-n}=-\frac{1}{2}f''(0),
$$
which implies $(1)$.

**Note.** If $\,f(0)=0$, $f'(0)=1$, $f''(0)=\cdots=f^{(k-1)}(0)=0\,$ and $f^{(k)}(0)<0$, then
$$
n^{1/(k-1)}a_n\to \left(-\frac{k!}{(k-1)f^{(k)}(0)}\right)^{1/(k-1)}.
$$
For example, if $a_0>0$ and $a_{n+1}=\sin a_n$, then $\sqrt{n}a_n\to \sqrt{3}$.

Comment: @OlivierMoschetta It should be $f'(0)=1$. For example, if $f(x)=\log(1+x)$, then $f(0)=0$ and  $f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$ and $f'(0)=1$.